# Target child on parent hover using @emotion/react css

Tags: emotion

This doesn't seem to be an issue with `styled` in Emotion, but I can't do it with `css`...

Just like the title says, I have a child component that is `display: none`, I want to change it to `display: block` when the parent is hovered.

You can see it not working in [this code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-snow-b76o3j?file=/src/App.js) with the following code:

```
const child = css`
  background: yellow;
  display: none;
`;

const parent = css`
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  &:hover {
    background: green;
  }
  &:hover ${child} {
    display: block;
  }
`;
```

Is it just not an option with Emotion's css?